# Journey vs travel

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, nouns

> After Paul came back from his expedition around Africa he started to
>   write a book about his...

What would you say, his **journey** or his **travels** (plural) if there is no other context? It seemed logical to me to use journey because it is not clear from this sentence that he made any other travels besides this African expedition.

But I was told that it is correct to use **travels** here because the meaning of the word **travel** is broader while **journey** usually means a trip from point A to point B so it is not correct for a travel **around Africa**.

Comment: I would prefer this construction: "When Paul returned from his expedition to Africa, he began writing a book about his travels." I agree with you that "journey" or "journeys" should be saved for later use and not used in this introductory sentence.

Comment: Note that *his expedition around Africa* implies a single (goal-oriented) series of journeys. It's largely a matter of opinion, but personally I'd say use ***journeys*** if you want to focus on *the process of moving between* many different places, or ***travels*** if you're more interested in the fact of having visited and spend time in multiple locations (and the contrast between them, for example).

Comment: Note: I also agree with @FumbleFingers.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think "correct" is really the right word here (of the four permutations, only singular ***travel*** would be ridiculously non-idiomatic, and even that wouldn't exactly be "incorrect" - just "unlikely"). But I can easily see the case for singular ***journey*** if one wanted to allude to Paul's expedition as representing a metaphoric "voyage of [self] discovery". On the other hand, *You should write a book about your **travels*** is so common it's almost a cliche, but you'd rarely hear *You should write a book about your **journeys.***

Answer (score 1):

"expedition around Africa" implies that Paul travelled in multiple places (because the word around is used). It is more appropriate to use the plural form of journey or travel here.

> After Paul came back from his expedition around Africa he started to
>   write a book about his travels.

You could reformat it as suggested by Mark Hubbard:

> When Paul returned from his expedition to Africa, he began writing a
>   book about his travels.